# UICollectionView.backgroundView broken

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem with backgroundView property. I tried to add an imageView to background like this

```
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Fridge_background")!
    let backgroundView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    collectionView?.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

but the problem is that it did not even add this view to view hierarchy. I have already read [this article](https://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/), but this solution did not help me either. What it can be and how did I can fix it? Funny think is that in tableView similar property work just fine as it must.

Comment: I tried this in my code and it worked fine, are you using storyboard or creating views programmatically?

Comment: CollectionView was created in storyboard

Comment: You are writing this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: It was copy-pasted directly from viewDidLoad

Comment: I have already tried to add simple UIView instance with backgroundColor = UIColor.black(), but this did not add a view to hierarchy either.

Comment: I made a dummy project and set the image as background , it still works, I would say please go through again the connections and if possible make a new simple small project and try it on that.

Comment: Step through in debug and make sure `backgroundImage` is valid, `backgroundView` is valid and `collectionView` is valid. That code worked just fine for me as well.

Comment: I have already created sample project and check valid of backgroundImage and it still does not work. Can it be a bug in Xcode? I have already one after installing Visual Studio for Mac, and I was forced to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @IBOutlet for the win.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot to all of you. How I understand, it's a local bug that occurs  only on my machine. Seems like it's time to reinstall Xcode again.

Answer (score 0):

Broken it is indeed.
I was researching improper positioning of uicollectionview background view
and run into this:

https://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/

describes your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work well in the `UIColllectionViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` method. All behaviors matched expectations.

```
        let myView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        let image = UIImage(named: "image name")
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: image!.size))
        imageView.image = image
        myView.addSubview(imageView)
        self.collectionView.backgroundView = myView
```